# Duplicate the Queue Elements in java

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

Write a function named doubleQueue() that accepts a reference to a queue of integers as a parameter
and replaces every element with two copies of itself.

For example, if a queue named q stores {11, 12, 13}, the call of doubleQueue(q); should change it to store {11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13}.

Constraints: Do not use any auxiliary collections as storage.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any auxiliary collections, the Queue needs to be a LinkedList. Then you're able to iterate through it backward and add each element in front of itself.

```java
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.lang.RuntimeException;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    queue.add(1);
    queue.add(2);
    queue.add(3);

    doubleQueue(queue);

    System.out.println(queue);
  }

  public static void doubleQueue(Queue<Integer> queue) {
    if (!(queue instanceof LinkedList))
      throw new RuntimeException("Queue needs to be of type LinkedList.");

    LinkedList<Integer> list = (LinkedList<Integer>) queue;

    for (int i = list.size(); i > 0; i--) {
      list.add(i, list.get(i - 1));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way?

Answer (score -1):

One way could be to make a copy of the queue and then merge it with the original queue.
If queue is implemented using linkedList then you can use `clone()` to create a shallow copy and then merge it with the original.

Or you can create an array using the linkedList, then append the array to the end of the linkedlist then sort the linkedList (or convert this entire to array and then sort the array and then convert back to linkedList).

Comment: The question specified that you cannot use additional collections as helpers for storage.